# ServiceWorker: offline-plugin and Firebase

Tags: firebase, service-worker

i'm working with [offline-plugin](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) and i'm trying to enable background notifications using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive?hl=en)

I've noticed that firebase `setBackgroundMessageHandler` method need to run in a ServiceWorker. I have an auto generated service worker by the `offline-plugin` and i don't know how to add that method to the existent ServiceWorker or if i can create a new one for Firebase.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i've managed to do it. You can add a bootstrap service worker using ServiceWorker `entry` option in the OfflinePlugin initialization this way:

```
plugins: [
    ...,
    new OfflinePlugin({
        ...,
        ServiceWorker: {
            ...,
            entry: 'my-sw.js'
        }
    })
]
```

Then i put my firebase-sw.js code in the `my-sw.js` file

Cheers